# What is the type that represents any object of any custom class?

Tags: python, mypy

What's a type that accepts an instantiation of any custom class, but not for example, instatiations of builtins like `int`, `str`, `dict`, etc.

In other words, what would `MyType` be here:

```py
def func(x: MyType) -> None:
    pass

func([])  # should have type error

func(5)  # should have type error

class Dog:
    pass

func(Dog())  # no type error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such type. Python does not distinguish built-in and custom types that way.

Answer (score -1):

Python does not enforce strict typing. Even if you chose **not** to provide MyType in the function definition, your code will still work fine.

If you would like to anyway have MyType in function definition for better readability, `MyType` should be `Dog`. Here's a screenshot from PyCharm which points the same fact:

[image]

Edit:
For your function to accept any data type, you'd need to import `Any` from `typing` module:

```
from typing import Any

def myfunc(x: Any):
    pass
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want `x` to accept _any_ instantiation of _any_ custom class, not just accept instantiations of `Dog`.  And do that while rejecting instantiations of `int`, `list`, etc.

Comment: @Garrett I have updated the answer with an edit to align it with your requirement. You'd need to import 'Any' from 'typing' module. Please accept and upvote, if this resolves your query!

Comment: @sxddhxrthx: `Any` accepts anything, including types like `int` and `list` that the questioner specifically wants to exclude.